# Hybrid Sampling Scheme Idea?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, sampling, interpolation, reconstruction

I am facing a problem which I could not find any robust solution for . Assume we have a signal, $x$, composed of sum of a few sinusoidal.  e.g. $$x=A_1\sin(\omega_1t+\phi_1)+A_2\sin(\omega_2t+\phi_2)+A_3\sin(\omega_3t+\phi_3)+\ldots +A_n\sin(\omega_nt+\phi_n)$$
We have sampled the signal,  ($30\%$) of samples are high resolution 10-Bits and the other $70\%$ are low resolution 3-4 Bits samples. 
[image]
Also,assume a sub-set of frequencies are known(for example $\omega_1, \omega_5$ and  $\omega_{10}$ out of $\omega_1,\ldots , \omega_5$ are known).

1. How can we reconstruct the original signal?
2. Is there any method which can reconstruct the signal from these samples?

Moreover, we have these assumptions:

- The sinusoidals have unknown amplitudes ($A_n$)
- of course, we know when the high resolution samples occur
- We know maximum number of possible independent frequencies in the
  summation
- and spacing of sampling of high resolution sampling is reconfiguration
  and can be programmed to be regular or random (whichever is
  suitable?)

For examples, the below is a signal sampled uniformly at Nyquist rate($50\textrm{ Hz}$), with two components of $25\textrm{ Hz}$ and $12\textrm{ Hz}$. Green samples are high resolution samples, red samples are samples with considerable error (low resolution) and the blue curve is the original signal.
 [image]

Following code provides an example of mentioned data:

```
Fs=1000; %sampling frequency 
t=(0:800).*(1/Fs);
x=0.5*sin(2*pi*300*t)+0.6*cos(2*pi*460*t)+0.2*cos(2*pi*60*t)+0.8*cos(2*pi*40*t)+1.6*cos(2*pi*12*t); %Original Signal
NoisySample=x+0.1*randn(size(x));           %Uniform Noisy Samples
ClearSamples=x(1:10:end); %Clear Samples
```

I would appreciate any hint and direction.

Comment: I've tested the curve fitting, but unfortunately it is too unstable. I have solution in which using Fourier transform of low resolution samples I find the frequencies, and then  fit a model of sum of sins to high resolution samples, but it heavily depends upon resolution of FFT which obviously is not high. I have successfully recovered, in some cases, the original signal using curve fitting toolbox of matlab. I have tried compressive sensing but it is too complex computationally and I am not seeking a method in that field.

Answer (score 1):

i will reframe the question a little:

we have

$$\begin{align}
 x(t) &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^N r_n \cos(\omega_n t + \phi_n) \ + \ \epsilon(t) \\ 
\\
  &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_n \cos(\omega_n t) + b_n \sin(\omega_n t) \ + \ \epsilon(t) \\ 
\end{align}$$

where

$$\begin{align}
 a_n &= r_n \cos(\phi_n) \\ 
 b_n &= -r_n \sin(\phi_n) \\ 
\\
 r_n &= \sqrt{a_n^2 + b_n^2} \\
\\
 \phi_n &= \arg\{a_n - j b_n \} \\ 
        &= -\operatorname{atan2}(b_n,a_n) \\
\end{align}$$

and $\epsilon(t)$ is the unknown error signal.

first you have to assume that $\epsilon(t)$ contains no components having frequencies of any of the $\omega_n$ in it, otherwise that component will just team up with the component having amplitude $r_n$.

if you know all of the $\omega_n$ in advance, you can calculate all of the $a_n, b_n$ by using an inner product:

$$\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac{\omega_n}{M\pi} \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0+\tfrac{2M\pi}{\omega_n}} x(t) \cos(\omega_n t) \ dt \\
\\
b_n &= \frac{\omega_n}{M\pi} \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0+\tfrac{2M\pi}{\omega_n}} x(t) \sin(\omega_n t) \ dt \\
\end{align}$$

$t_0$ can be the most convenient time for you and $M$ should be a large positive integer (and need not be the same $M$ for each frequency component $\omega_n$), but the wider your integration is, the better error rejection you will have.

from the $a_n$ and $b_n$ coefficients, you can calculate $r_n$ and $\phi_n$.

Comment: thanks, though your answer does not directly address my question (seems I failed to convey), but indeed very useful for my other work. Since the formulation all are continuous, I wonder if I can use it in discrete domain?